# Why the objc_class structure doesn't have list of objc_property

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

When I look at the file "objc/runtime.h", I find the definition of objc_class structure like this

```
Class super_class                                        OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
const char *name                                         OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
long version                                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
long info                                                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
long instance_size                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
struct objc_ivar_list *ivars                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
struct objc_method_list **methodLists                    OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
struct objc_cache *cache                                 OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
struct objc_protocol_list *protocols                     OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

it doesn't contain the list of objc_property, but contains the list of protocol, method, ivar. So I think where the list of objc_property stores. Maybe I shouldn't understand this detail, but I'm interested in it.

Comment: Properties are a convenience to create ivars and methods

Comment: A property mainly converted to  `get`and `set`method,and `ivar`.So,there is no need to store `objc_property `.`@property`is for compiler.

Comment: To elaborate: The class structure has the members required for using the class at runtime: it's name, the ivars, etc.  The property declarations are also available, to get the attributes such as (non)atomic or strong/weak, but they aren't needed to use the class at runtime, so they aren't part of the class structure.

Comment: @Leo, do you mean there is no memory to store the information about property？ But if so, how the method "class_copyPropertyList" works. this method will return An array of pointers of type objc_property_t describing the properties declared by the class

Comment: @Avi, Yes, I agree about you said. But as Leo said, do you mean there is no need to store objc_property too?

Comment: @Leo, 哦哦，你的意思是runtime 会根据ivar和method转换为objc_property吗？

Comment: @Leo, 我尝试了一下写了set和get方法，ivar也有了，但是“class_copyPropertyList”不会出现那个属性

Comment: @Leo, 你的意思是假如这个ivar是通过property合成的，它会有特殊的标识，到时候调用返回objc_property的时候就能转换了